# Rspec how to test a Sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec, sidekiq, stub

I have a Sidekiq job that looks something like this:

```
class Arbitrary::MarkSold < ApplicationJob
  def perform(item_id)
    return if Rails.env.test?
    item = Item.find_by(item_id)
    item.sold = true
    item.save
  end
end
```

And a corresponding RSpec test that looks like this:

```
Rspec.describe Arbitrary::MarkSold, type: :job do
  describe 'perform' do
    it 'runs' do
      expect(Arbitrary::Marksold).to receive(:perform).and_return(nil)
      MarkSold.new.perform(34)
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to run this test, I get a failure with this error:

```
Arbitrary::MarkSold does not implement: perform`.
```

However, I can clearly see that `Arbitrary::MarkSold` has a `perform` method.

I've read [Method Stubs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs) but couldn't make heads or tails out of it, or figure out how to apply it to this situation.

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers or links to documentation other than the one I've linked. As a beginner I find that the rspec docs aren't very beginner-friendly. Thank you in advance!

Ruby version: 2.4.9
Rails version: 5.1.7
RSpec version: 3.7

Answer (score 1):

I use `have_enqueued_job` to test if the job gets enqueued assuming that is what you are trying to test.  It seems like it.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher

Comment: Thanks! How do I induce this test to fail?

Comment: This worked, but it doesn't really answer my question. I'll be writing some other tests and I was hoping to gain a better understanding about why my code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For the next users stumbling upon this page from Google (like me)...

If you are looking to test your Sidekiq job, consider that maybe what you are trying to test is the content of `perform` and if so you can test it directly like any other ruby object.

source: https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-workers-directly

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in what you are doing:

```rb
expect(Arbitrary::Marksold).to receive(:perform).and_return(nil)
```

In the snippet above, you are expecting that the class `Arbitrary::Marksold` to receive `perform`, but you are not expecting that an **instance** should receive `perform`. That's why you are getting the `does not implement: perform` error.

You could (I did not test it, so you may have to adjust one or another thing):

```rb
marksold_spy = instance_spy(Arbitrary::Marksold)
allow(Arbitrary::Marksold).to(receive(:new).and_return(marksold_spy))
expect(marksold_spy).to(receive(:perform).and_return(nil))
```

But the above isn't the way how I'd do it. The way I'd do it:

```rb
class Arbitrary::MarkSold
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(item_id)
    item = Item.update(item_id, sold: true)
  end
end
```

And my test:

```rb
Rspec.describe Arbitrary::MarkSold, type: :job do
  describe 'perform' do
    it 'runs' do
      item = create(:item, sold: false)
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
        described_class.perform_async(item.id)
      end
      expect(item.reload.sold).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

To read a little bit more about `Sidekiq::Testing`, you can go through [this link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing)