# How to fake a Job method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I have a Rails `model` which is `deactivated` by default. A Sidekiq job is `activating` it after success. All my specs are failing after implementing this job. How can I "stub" / "fake" that database change to get my specs falling **without** changing all of them to `Model.unscoped`

Maybe somehow a helper_function could be called to mock that job function.

```rb
class Model 
  attribute :active # false by default in Database
  default_scope { where(:active => true) }
  after_create :run_job, if: -> { saved_change_to_something? }


  def run_job
    MyJob.perform_async(id)
  end

  def mark_visible!
    update_column(:active, true)
  end


  def stuff_to_do_in_job
    update_column(:active, false)

    # do long term stuff
  end

end

class MyJob
  include Sidekiq::Job

  def perform(id)
    model = Model.find(id)
    if stuff_to_do_in_job
      model.mark_visible!
    end
end



RSpec.describe Model, type: :model do
  it "is active after saved"
    model = Model.new(model_attributes)

    model.save
    # --> • <---  somehow mock here a running job, setting model to true
    expect(model.active).to be_truthy

end
```

Of course I can change all functions where any `Model.find` is needed to set to `Model.unscoped.find` but that looks awkward

Do I have a test modelling issue?

Comment: refer this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029828/17983466

Comment: @SachinSingh the thing is, that I don't want to test the behavior of the Job. This is already working. Instead the job does something to the model, which should regularly be done in the background. The `stuff_to_do_in_job ` was normally done in an `after_create ` callback. Which now should be done in a Job. When I implement that Job. All my old "Model" specs are failing, because the job isn't running in model tests. This is what I try to "mock" ,"stub" or "fake". Hope that's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to mock the job after each `Model` creation. Just create the `Model` with `active: true` in your specs that do not test that specific behaviour.

Then you can create one spec to make sure that the job is being scheduled i.e.:

```
expect{ model.save }.to have_enqueued_job(MyJob)
```

And finally create a new file for the specs of `MyJob`, where you assert that it is doing what it should do when executed.

Comment: the problem is, that this job runs after creation of each Model or if an attribute was changed. ( exposed more details in the after_create hook)

Comment: You probably have `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test` inside `config/environment/test.rb` (if you don't, add it). That will prevent this job from running and instead being enqueued with TestAdapter (https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/TestAdapter.html). 

So you can pretend it never ran and move on with testing other things you need to test for your Model. You only need to test that the job is enqueued on Model creation and that it does what it should (in another file that will test the job specifically).

Comment: If you need your Model to be active for testing other behaviours, just create it with `active: true`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!! Thank you for all your suggestions.

**It was a design problem:**

What I did was to deactivate the Model in the model itself, and after that fired a job, where within this job it was activated again.

The way I am doing it now, is deactivating it within the Model.

There are two ways:

- Deactivate it within the Job and at the end activating it again or
- Deactivating it right before calling the Job and activating it at the
  end of the job.

```rb
class Model 
  attribute :active # false by default in Database
  default_scope { where(:active => true) }
  after_create :run_job, if: -> { saved_change_to_something? }


  def run_job
    # or deactivate it here
    mark_invisible!

    MyJob.perform_async(id)
  end

  def mark_visible!
    update_column(:active, true)
  end

  def mark_invisible!
    update_column(:active, false)
  end


  def stuff_to_do_in_job
    # don't do it here mark_invisible!
    # do long term stuff
  end

end

class MyJob
  include Sidekiq::Job

  def perform(id)
    model = Model.find(id)
    model.mark_invisible! # either here
    if stuff_to_do_in_job
      model.mark_visible!
    end
end
```